# o que é um service e qual sua diferença para um controller?

Tags: java, design-pattern

Tenho lido muitos artigos e visto muitas aulas sobre Java e ultimamente me deparo muito com o conceito de serviços e controladores, tenho a clareza do papel do Controller dentro de uma estrutura MVC, mas tenho algumas dúvidas sobre o papel do service dentro de um projeto:

Qual seria o papel do service exatamente ?

O que exatamente difere um service de um controller ?

De onde surgiu esse conceito de service ? ( Faz parte de alguma nova arquitetura ? )

Vocês tem algum exemplo de projeto que mostre com clareza a diferença entre um e outro ou qualquer material de estudo que explique isso mais detalhadamente ?

Encontrei algumas respostas no Stack Overflow global, mas nada que deixasse isso claro para mim.

Comment: Resumidamente, o controlador é responsável por receber uma requisição HTTP e gerar uma resposta HTTP... E só. Toda a lógica da aplicação deve ficar em outra estrutura, geralmente no serviço. Esse estereótipo foge daquele padrão que controlador chama o modelo. Aqui o controlador chama o serviço e o serviço que chama o modelo e, assim, você fica livre para executar uma mesma ação de diferentes origens que não sejam requisições HTTP, tal como uma chamada por CLI, por exemplo.

Comment: Acho que estou começando a entender o conceito, é que sempre utilizei o resources para expor meus endpoints e ele passava os objetos gerados para o controller e esse fazia seu trabalho, então diferentes formas de acesso HTTP, gRPC entre outras todas tinham um pacote especifico que cuidavam da serialização dos dados para serem enviados ao controller.

Comment: Nesse caso quem fica responsável por todo fluxo que antes era do controller é o service e o trabalho do controller fica como algo mais genérico como o pacote resources que eu citei ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O papel do que chamamos de Controllers é de orquestração dos dados recebidos pela sua aplicação Java. Ele deve tratar as entradas do sistema com algumas verificações, como de tipos de dados, por exemplo, se um parâmetro obrigatório foi enviado na requisição. Depois dessas verificações, o Controller deve passar os dados recebidos pela requisição para o que chamamos de Services.

Os Services são responsáveis pela lógica de negócio da sua aplicação, além de ser responsável por se comunicar com as camadas mais internas do Software, como por exemplo, uma camada de Dados.

O conceito de camada de serviços não é novo, já é utilizado no mercado há algum tempo. Ele surgiu da necessidade de uma camada responsável por fazer as tratativas de regras de negócios, tentando desacoplar a camada de Controladores da camada de Modelos. Essa separação de camadas é uma das formas de arquitetar a sua aplicação, mas existem muitas outras, e elas são utilizadas para atender requisitos não funcionais, como manutenibilidade, reusabilidade, desempenho e etc.

Por exemplo, nessa imagem podemos ver uma arquitetura em camadas chamada de Clean Architecture. Recomendo a leitura do livro Clean Architecture do Robert Martin para conhecer mais detalhes.

[image: Clean architecture]

Comment: Se não me engano essa arquitetura é a mesma chamada de arquitetura Hexagonal certo ?

Comment: Gostei bastante da sua explicação e ficou bem claro agora o papel dessa camada e a divisão de tarefas entre a controller e service